# SharePoint Designer Workflow Change the display of From Address information

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, notifications

We have a SharePoint Designer Approval workflow on a SharePoint online list. When workflow sends out notification, it is being sent from "no-reply@sharepointonline.com" which is fine. Along with it, it also displays the site title as below screenshot. Can we change that ? Like instead of "Information Technology" in below, can we display some custom text?

EDIT: Iterating again on point that email address is fine. It's Ok if we cannot change the email address. Just the label which is actually the site title, can that be changed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change in from address is not possible in SharePoint online.

Comment: I do not want to change the from address, just the label.

Answer (score 0):

The From address of emails sent from workflow is fixed to the address set in **Outgoing Email Settings** Central Administration and can not be changed.

[Send e-mail in a workflow](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-HA010239042.aspx#BM9)

> **The following options are not
>   supported by the current version of
>   the Send an Email action:**
>
> Specifying
>   an address on the From line. E-mail
>   messages sent by the workflow always
>   show the e-mail address specified by
>   the server administrator on the From
>   line. Only the server administrator
>   can change this, and it can only be
>   changed for all notifications in the
>   current Web application, not per
>   workflow.

There is a project on Codeplex ([spdactivities > Send Email Extended](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/)) that allows you to do this.

Alternatively you can send mail using .net's [system.net.mail](http://www.systemnetmail.com/) without these restrictions

**Note**: You cannot change the site name either from `from` email address.

Comment: Thanks for the information about way to customize email address.  I understand that E-Mail address cannot be changed OOTB. Wanted to check if Site Title that is displayed, can that be changed?As highlighted in screenshot above.

Comment: No, you cannot change the site name either.